# Why I can't add reference to normal class library in MVC6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package-restore

Did anyone knows why I can't add a reference to the old class library type to the new templates WebAPI or Class library (package)? what the idea behind that? Also if it's something good? what do you think, should it be optional or must as now?

I could think of this's maybe better to restore the library from nuGet but what if I don't deploy my library to the nuGet? what if my machine not connected to the internet and what if my build server not connected to the internet either? Shall I make a local nuGet repository?

[image]

And if this is not supported how I am going to test this type of project?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you are referencing a .NET class library that doesn't run on Core CLR. DNX now runs on a lightweight .NET library that is made up of NuGet packages. So it wouldn't support legacy desktop .NET 4.0+ components.

Comment: So how to test project that run on Core CRL. DNX? I create a unit test project and I failed to add reference to that project? Please see the update of my question.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918305/mocking-framework-for-asp-net-core-5-0

Comment: It seems that no more MSTest "Goodbye Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework and hello xUnit.net!"

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/24/top-10-changes-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6