# how to unit test asp.net core application with constructor dependency injection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, testing, dependency-injection

I have a asp.net core application that uses dependency injection defined in the startup.cs class of the application:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:FotballConnection:DefaultConnection"]));


        // Repositories
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserRoleRepository, UserRoleRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ILoggingRepository, LoggingRepository>();

        // Services
        services.AddScoped<IMembershipService, MembershipService>();
        services.AddScoped<IEncryptionService, EncryptionService>();

        // new repos
        services.AddScoped<IMatchService, MatchService>();
        services.AddScoped<IMatchRepository, MatchRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IMatchBetRepository, MatchBetRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ITeamRepository, TeamRepository>();

        services.AddScoped<IFootballAPI, FootballAPIService>();
```

This allows something like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MatchController : AuthorizedController
{
    private readonly IMatchService _matchService;
    private readonly IMatchRepository _matchRepository;
    private readonly IMatchBetRepository _matchBetRepository;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly ILoggingRepository _loggingRepository;

    public MatchController(IMatchService matchService, IMatchRepository matchRepository, IMatchBetRepository matchBetRepository, ILoggingRepository loggingRepository, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _matchService = matchService;
        _matchRepository = matchRepository;
        _matchBetRepository = matchBetRepository;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _loggingRepository = loggingRepository;
    }
```

This is very neat. But becomes a problem when I want to unit test. Because my test library does not have a startup.cs where I setup dependency injection. So a class with these interfaces as params will just be null.

```
namespace TestLibrary
{
    public class FootballAPIService
    {
        private readonly IMatchRepository _matchRepository;
        private readonly ITeamRepository _teamRepository;

        public FootballAPIService(IMatchRepository matchRepository, ITeamRepository teamRepository)

        {
            _matchRepository = matchRepository;
            _teamRepository = teamRepository;
```

In the code above, in the test library, **_matchRepository** and **_teamRepository**, will just be **null**. :(

Can I do something like ConfigureServices, where I define dependency injection in my test library project?

Comment: As part of your test you should setup the dependencies for your System Under Test (SUT). Usually you do this by creating mock's of the dependencies before creating the SUT. But to create the SUT simply calling `new SUT(mockDependency);` is fine for your test.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your controllers in .net core have dependency injection in mind from the start, but this does not mean you are required to use a dependency injection container.

Given a simpler class like:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    private readonly IMyInterface _myInterface;

    public MyController(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        _myInterface = myInterface;
    }

    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return Json(_myInterface.Get());
    }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    IEnumerable<MyObject> Get();
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public IEnumerable<MyObject> Get()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

So in your app, you're using the dependency injection container in your `startup.cs`, which does nothing more than provide a concretion of `MyClass` to use when `IMyInterface` is encountered.  This does not mean it is the only way of  getting instances of `MyController` however.

In a ***unit*** testing scenario, you can (and should) provide your own implementation (or mock/stub/fake) of `IMyInterface` as so:

```
public class MyTestClass : IMyInterface
{
    public IEnumerable<MyObject> Get()
    {
        List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
        // populate list
        return list;
    }        
}
```

and in your test:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyControllerTests
{

    MyController _systemUnderTest;
    IMyInterface _myInterface;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _myInterface = new MyTestClass();
        _systemUnderTest = new MyController(_myInterface);
    }

}
```

So for the scope of unit testing `MyController`, the actual implementation of `IMyInterface` does not matter (and ***should not*** matter), only the interface itself matters.  We have provided a "fake" implementation of `IMyInterface` through `MyTestClass`, but you could also do this with a mock like through `Moq` or `RhinoMocks`.

Bottom line, you do not actually need the dependency injection container to accomplish your tests, only a separate, controllable, implementation/mock/stub/fake of your tested classes dependencies.

Comment: Perfect answer. I would even go as far as not using a DI container at all ever in your unit test. Offcourse except for unit tests aiming to test the correctness of the DI configuration, like the order of applied decorators for example

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this is when you have classes upon classes that all need a number of dependencies to be injected. What I'd like to do is be able to register default implementations (or mocks with default behaviors) so that I can instantiate those object graphs without having to setup 30 dependencies first, but rather reconfigure the ones that I need for the test.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic that's what Testing and Mocking frameworks are for.  nUnit allows you to create one-time or run-per-test methods that allow you to mock everything, then in your tests only be concerned with configuring the method you are testing.  Actually using DI for a Test means it's not longer a *Unit-Test* but an *Integration-Test* with Microsofts (or 3rd Partys) DI.

Comment: "Actually using DI for a Test means it's not longer a Unit-Test" can't really agree with you there, at least not at face value. Oftentimes, the DI is necessary to simply initialize the class so that the unit *can* be tested. The point being that the dependencies are mocked so that you can test the unit's behavior around the dependency. I think you might be referring to a scenario where one would be injecting a fully functional dependency, then it might be an integration test, unless the dependencies of that object are also mocked. There are many one-off scenarios that could be discussed.

Comment: We use dependency injection heavily in our unit tests.  We use them extensively for mocking purposes.  I'm not sure why at all you would not want to use DI in your tests.  We're not software engineering our infrastructure for tests, but rather we're using DI to make it really easy to mock and inject objects that a test would need.  And we can fine tune what objects are available in our `ServiceCollection` from the start.  It's particularly helpful for scaffolding, and it's helpful for integration tests too so... yeah I'd be FOR using DI in your tests.

Comment: I agree with @Sinaesthetic, please have a look at my answer below where I use asp.net core DI and Moq to inject mock instance objects : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724738/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-core-application-with-constructor-dependency-injection/67806752#answer-67806752

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. I can't believe it's not the highest voted answer - all the higher voted answers are missing the point. The point is you should isolate the part of the system under test, when you use a DI container, you are recreating the whole system. You shouldn't use a DI container in your unit tests, except when you use it in your system under test, which is usually unnecessary. If you've got a lot of dependencies, you can mock them using e.g. NSubstitute. If that still feels like a lot of effort for each test, you've probably got too many dependencies

Answer (score 212):

Although @Kritner's answer is correct, I prefer the following for code integrity and better DI experience:

```
[TestClass]
public class MatchRepositoryTests
{
    private readonly IMatchRepository matchRepository;

    public MatchRepositoryTests()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddTransient<IMatchRepository, MatchRepositoryStub>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        matchRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<IMatchRepository>();
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you get the generic GetService<> method?

Comment: `GetService<>` has some overloads that can be found with `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: I just tested this out. this is a far more valid answer than the marked answer. This uses DI. I tried using this over the same extension function that I use for the website. this feature works perfectly

Comment: Added "using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" but "AddTransient" is still missing from ServiceCollection. Any1 knows how to fix this?

Comment: This does not *Unit-Test* the Service, this is an *Integration-Test* with Microsofts DI.  Microsoft already has unit tests to test DI, so there is no reason to do this.  If you want to test that and object is registered, that is a separation of concerns and should be in it's own test.  *Unit-Testing* and object means testing the object itself with no external dependencies.

Comment: I can´t add an httpservice to IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection(); services.AddHttpClient<Iinterfac, eimplementation>(); how can I add it?

Comment: How do I mock using moq while using this way?

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful, when we want to test methods of different service implementations or when the one implementation we used changes. Makes for a way more maintainable code for unit tests, IMO.

Comment: is it better to do this service locating either in Constructor or create a TestInitialize method in put it in there?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I believe you're missing the purpose here, eg I have a class which has multiple dependencies and each of these have multiple dependencies. By using the DI to create these objects in tests, like this answer, I'm not testing the DI, I'm just constructing my objects using DI instead of writing 30 lines of "newing up" code to do the same thing - which would require a lot of time to figure out. So, this is simply using DI to construct  your objects for unit testing. If using DI is useful in prod code, it has to be useful for test code.

Answer (score 55):

A simple way, I wrote a generic dependency resolver helper class and then built the IWebHost in my unit test class.

**Generic Dependency Resolver**

```
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
        public class DependencyResolverHelper
        {
            private readonly IWebHost _webHost;
    
            /// <inheritdoc />
            public DependencyResolverHelper(IWebHost webHost) => _webHost = webHost;
    
            public T GetService<T>()
            {
                var serviceScope = _webHost.Services.CreateScope();
                var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                  var scopedService = services.GetRequiredService<T>();
                  return scopedService;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(e);
                   throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Unit Test Project:**

```
      [TestFixture]
        public class DependencyResolverTests
        {
            private DependencyResolverHelper _serviceProvider;

            public DependencyResolverTests()
            {

                var webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .Build();
                _serviceProvider = new DependencyResolverHelper(webHost);
            }
    
            [Test]
            public void Service_Should_Get_Resolved()
            {
                
                //Act
                var YourService = _serviceProvider.GetService<IYourService>();
    
                //Assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(YourService);
            }
    

        }
```

Comment: a nice example about how to replace Autofac with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: Yes, this should be the default answer. We have placed an entire suite testing all the services to be injected, and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: hi @Joshua Duxbury can you help answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331395/net-core-dependency-injection-in-xunit-test-following-constructor-parameters trying to implement your solution, just sent 100 points looking at your other answers also, thanks !

Comment: Disposing the scope seems wrong to me - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescope?view=aspnetcore-2.2 - `Once Dispose is called, any scoped services that have been resolved from ServiceProvider will be disposed.`.

Comment: You may need to remove the "using" statement to avoid "disposed object error" on your DBcontexts

Comment: I don't understand what IWebHost is, and how I would translate this into my own unit test project.

Comment: Nice concise approach, thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Just to reiterate the comment above about the Using Statement and DbContext being disposed. Got me for a few hours that one!

Comment: No problem, glad everyone is finding it useful, I've updated the code and removed the using statement so no one else runs into that issue @StephenGarside

Comment: I can't get the `Startup` type in `.UseStartup<Startup>()` to resolve, maybe because I'm on .NET 6, which doesn't have a `Startup.cs`.

Comment: @TawabWakil were you able to solve it?

Comment: @VladL I never resolved the error, but instead ended up with a test class using `WebApplicationFactory` and `HttpClient`.

Comment: @TawabWakil correct, you can't use `UseStartup<Startup>()` in .Net 6+ unless you create your startup class or expose a pubic getter method for returning back the IApplicationBuilder inside the program.cs - [See here for info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254238/how-do-i-migrate-this-into-my-net-6-program-cs-file-without-using-the-startup-c)

Answer (score 20):

If you are using the `Program.cs` + `Startup.cs` convention and want to get this working quickly you can reuse your existing host builder with a one-liner:

```
using MyWebProjectNamespace;

public class MyTests
{
    readonly IServiceProvider _services = 
        Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[] { }).Build().Services; // one liner

    [Test]
    public void GetMyTest()
    {
        var myService = _services.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(myService);
    }
}
```

Sample `Program.cs` file from web project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MyWebProjectNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) =>
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you very much. I can see how setting up a new ServiceCollection in `[SetUp]` could be useful, or even mocking the dependencies. But really, what I wanna do is use the same service collection used by my web app, and run tests against the same environment. Cheers!

Comment: Brilliant in it's simplicity!

Comment: Awesome. Just that one liner got me going fairly quick on bunch of unit tests that I wanted to write. Thank you Matthew!

Answer (score 6):

You can use asp.net core DI and inject mocked instance objects in your tests.
Here is a full working example :

For the sake of the example :

- I only kept the `IMatchService` dependency from the code snippet of the initial question
- I added a `DoSomething` action in the `MatchController` so that there is someting to test.
- I added an `Add` method to the `IMatchService` and the `MatchService` classes so that there is soemthing to mock.

Please note that the methods that will have a `Setup` with `Moq` should be virtual.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MatchController : AuthorizedController
{
  private readonly IMatchService _matchService;

  public MatchController(IMatchService matchService)
  {
    _matchService = matchService;
  }

  public virtual int DoSomething()
  {
    return _matchService.Add(1, 2);
  }
}

public interface IMatchService
{
  int Add(int a, int b);
}

public class MatchService : IMatchService
{
  public virtual int Add(int a, int b)
  {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

It's always possible to get the Mock by calling the `Mock.Get` method.
For conveniance for each dependency, I create two properties like `MatchService` and `MockedMatchService`.

```cs
public class MyTests
{
  protected IMatchService MatchService { get; set; }

  protected Mock<IMatchService> MockedMatchService => Mock.Get(MatchService);

  private IServiceProvider ServicesProvider { get; set; }

  [SetUp]
  public void SetupBeforeEachTest()
  {
    // Configure DI container
    ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(services);
    ServicesProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    // Use DI to get instances of IMatchService
    MatchService = ServicesProvider.GetService<IMatchService>();
  }

  // In this test I mock the Add method of the dependency (IMatchService) so that it returns a value I choose
  [Test]
  public void TestMethod()
  {
    // Prepare
    var matchController = ServicesProvider.GetService<MatchController>();
    int expectedResult = 5;
    MockedMatchService.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(expectedResult);

    // Act - This will call the real DoSomething method because the MatchController has comes from a Mock with CallBase = true
    int result = matchController.DoSomething();

    // Check
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
  }

  private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddScoped<IMatchService>();
    services.AddScoped<MatchController>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I worked over @madjack and @Kritner's answers and made my

> Basic Inheritable Base Test Class for Dependency Injection

Just register your services inside of it and inherite.

```
public class BaseTester 
{
    protected IProductService _productService; 
    protected IEmployeeService _employeeService; 

    public BaseTester()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddTransient<IProductService, ProductService>();
        services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        _productService = serviceProvider.GetService<IProductService>();
        _employeeService = serviceProvider.GetService<IEmployeeService>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Improved solution

I improved madjack's solution by wrapping it in single `abstract class` and adding four methods (including two `async` equivalents) with callbacks as parameters. `GetRequiredScopedService<TSvc>()` is using `private static` property `services` for caching now, so derived classes don't create new instances over and over. Another optimization is making `host` `static`, so we don't build it every time in derived classes. I also removed pointless try/catch:

```cs
    public abstract class TestWithDependencyInjection
    {
        private static readonly IHost host =
            Program.CreateHostBuilder(Constants.CommandArgs).Build();
        private static readonly IList<object> services =
            new List<object>();

        private IServiceScope svcScope;

        protected async Task<TResult> UseSvcAsync<TSvc, TResult>(
            Func<TSvc, Task<TResult>> callback, 
            bool shouldBeDisposed = true)
        {
            var scopedSvc = GetRequiredScopedService<TSvc>();
            TResult result = await callback(scopedSvc);
            if(shouldBeDisposed) 
                svcScope.Dispose();
            return result;
        }

        protected async Task UseSvcAsync<TSvc>(
            Func<TSvc, Task> callback)
        {
            var scopedSvc = GetRequiredScopedService<TSvc>();
            await callback(scopedSvc);
            svcScope.Dispose();
        }

        protected TResult UseSvc<TSvc, TResult>(
            Func<TSvc, TResult> callback, bool shouldBeDisposed = true)
        {
            var scopedSvc = GetRequiredScopedService<TSvc>();
            TResult result = callback(scopedSvc);
            if(shouldBeDisposed)
                svcScope.Dispose();
            return result;
        }

        protected void UseSvc<TSvc>(Action<TSvc> callback)
        {
            var scopedSvc = GetRequiredScopedService<TSvc>();
            callback(scopedSvc);
            svcScope.Dispose();
        }

        private TSvc GetRequiredScopedService<TSvc>()
        {
            var requiredScopedSvc = (TSvc)services.SingleOrDefault(
                svc => svc is TSvc);
            if (requiredScopedSvc != null)
                return requiredScopedSvc;
            svcScope = host.Services.CreateScope();
            requiredScopedSvc = svcScope.ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<TSvc>();
            services.Add(requiredScopedSvc);
            return requiredScopedSvc;
        }
    }
```

###### Example of returning `async` `result` from used injected service:

```cs
            int foobarsCount = await UseSvcAsync<IFoobarSvc, int>(
                    foobarSvc => foobarSvc.GetCountAsync());
```

###### Additional information

I added optional `shouldBeDisposed` argument set on `true` to methods returning `TResult` and `Task<TResult>` in case, when you want to use same instance of service outside of callback's body:

```cs
            IFoobarSvc foobarSvc = UseSvc<IFoobarSvc, IFoobarSvc>(
                    foobarSvc => foobarSvc, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use default .NET providers or other added services :

```cs
public UnitTest() {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IAbstractFoo, ConcreteFoo>();//add the service
    var app = builder.Build();    
    _foo = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAbstractFoo>();//retrieve added service
    _configuration = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();//or use default service
}

private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
private readonly IAbstractFoo _foo;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to inject those in a test class?
You would usually test the MatchController, for example, by using a tool like [RhinoMocks](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) to create stubs or mocks. Here's an example using that and MSTest, from which you can extrapolate:

```
[TestClass]
public class MatchControllerTests
{
    private readonly MatchController _sut;
    private readonly IMatchService _matchService;

    public MatchControllerTests()
    {
        _matchService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMatchService>();
        _sut = new ProductController(_matchService);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSomething_WithCertainParameters_ShouldDoSomething()
    {
        _matchService
               .Expect(x => x.GetMatches(Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
               .Return(new []{new Match()});

        _sut.DoSomething();

        _matchService.AssertWasCalled(x => x.GetMatches(Arg<string>.Is.Anything);
    }
```

Comment: Package RhinoMocks 3.6.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package RhinoMocks 3.6.1 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)

Comment: [Other frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34933925/1791065) are slowly taking this set.