# How to use NET.Core DI service in Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use Net.Core 2.1
I want to create UserManager instance in my Unit-Tests Project. In my API inject my dependency like:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<string>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But how to create UserManager instance in Tests Project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724738/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-core-application-with-constructor-dependency-injection

Comment: The answer is: **not at all**. Unit Tests are about testing a small piece of code, usually as little as a method call or class initialization (called unit). No dependencies are used at all, mocks at best to fake results of depending services in order to test a specific case. Real dependencies are only used in **integration tests**. your code needs to be abstracted properly and designed to play well with unit tests

Comment: yeap, i mean integration tests.